# Merge Dataframes based on values from different datasets

Tags: pandas, merge, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following data frames:

```
print(df)

id_code turnover costs 
 001      100     200
 002      100     200
 003      100     200
 004      100     200

print(df_db)

Description Code1, Code2, ... CodeN
Retail        001    002  ... nan
Wholesale     003    nan  ... nan
Supply        004    nan  ... nan
```

And I would like to create the following final_df, adding a column representing the description in df_db; basically, if the id_code is present in a row of df_db, merge the values:

```
print(final_df)

    id_code turnover costs Description
     001      100     200     Retail
     002      100     200     Retail
     003      100     200     Wholesale
     004      100     200     Supply
```

I tried with pd pivot but it does not report the desired result. How can I obtain final_df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) 
**if there are no duplicate codes in df_db**:

```
mapper=df_db.melt('Description').set_index('value')['Description']
df['Description']=df['id_code'].map(mapper)
print(df)
```

---

```
   id_code  turnover  costs Description
0        1       100    200      Retail
1        2       100    200      Retail
2        3       100    200   Wholesale
3        4       100    200      Supply
```

**Detail:**

```
print(mapper)
value
1       Retail
3    Wholesale
4       Supply
2       Retail
5    Wholesale
6       Supply
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `melt` before `merge`

```
final_df=df.merge(df_db.melt('Description').drop('variable',1),left_on='id_code',right_on='value').\
  drop('value',1)
Out[157]: 
  id_code  turnover  costs Description
0       1       100    200      Retail
1       2       100    200      Retail
2       3       100    200   Wholesale
3       4       100    200      Supply
```